# некорректный авто-комментарий

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок, комментарии, дубликаты

при голосовании за закрытие вопроса с резолюцией «дубликат» в качестве дубликата я указал ссылку `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478100/178576`

авто-комментарий, добавленный от моего имени, оказался битым.

наблюдать можно здесь: [GIT. Один репозиторий для 3х сайтов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/775427/178576)

Comment: Не влез в maxlength. Уже была такая тема.

Comment: дубликат на дубликате и дубликатом дублицирует

Comment: Ага, прошлый дубликат (этого) был мой и, что примечательно, при попытке предложить дубликатом тот же самый вопрос :)